# Children missing when changing ItemsSource of TreeView

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, treeview

I have multiple ObservableCollections of Items with children. I am trying to bind a TreeView to a collection, where the user will select the source during runtime. The user is able to drag and drop on the list to reorganise/edit the active source collection.

What I have tried works perfectly as long as you never switch to the previously selected source. Switching back to the previous source will result in missing children, with only the root items being displayed. This behaviour becomes even more inconsistent if children had been left expanded before returning, some children remaining, and others not.

xaml:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="8" Margin="8">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="8">
        <Button x:Name="ShowC1" Click="ShowC1_Click" Content="Container 1"/>
        <Button x:Name="ShowC2" Click="ShowC2_Click" Content="Container 2"/>
        <Button x:Name="ShowC3" Click="ShowC3_Click" Content="Container 3"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <muxc:TreeView x:Name="ItemTree" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Source}" Grid.Row="1">
        <muxc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <muxc:TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}" Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </muxc:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </muxc:TreeView>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private Container _con1, _con2, _con3;
    ExtendedObservableCollection<Item> Source = new ExtendedObservableCollection<Item>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _con1 = new Container("Container 1", 2);
        _con2 = new Container("Container 2", 3);
        _con3 = new Container("Container 3", 4);
    }

    private void ShowC1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Source.ReplaceAll(_con1.Items);
    }

    private void ShowC2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Source.ReplaceAll(_con2.Items);
    }

    private void ShowC3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Source.ReplaceAll(_con3.Items);
    }
}

public class Container
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Untitled";
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public Container(string title, int numItems)
    {
        Title = title;

        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item("Item " + i, i + 1));
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Item";
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public Item(string name, int numChildren)
    {
        Name = name;

        for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
        {
            Children.Add(new Item("Child " + i, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

ExtendedObservableCollection.cs

```
public class ExtendedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void ReplaceAll(ICollection<T> items)
    {
        this.Items.Clear();
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }
        this.OnCollectionChanged(
            new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        );
    }
}
```

Gif of issue:
[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSoV6.gif)

**Update:** Temporary workaround until I can find something nicer that works within what I need

Firstly, I noticed the collection wasn't even being updated from drag n' drop actions, but referencing the latest WinUI fixed that. I also changed the bindings to use x:Bind.

Second, I was able to get the children working in a rather dirty way by clearing the TreeView source, updating the bindings, then setting to a dummy collection (with at least 1 member, 0 results in failing to load only the last children for some reason), updating bindings, then finally setting it to the real source, and updating bindings one last time. Async delays were needed between each binding update to refresh the TreeView. The downside to this is that it introduces a frame of flicker for when the source is blank.

Comment: Hi, I reproduced your problem and it seems to be a cache issue. I have already reported this issue. If I have new progress, I will reply here. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been trying to tackle this in different ways for a few days now thinking it was purely just my lack of understanding with binding. Looking forward to an update.

Comment: Hi, before I get feedback, there is an easy way to solve the problem. When you press the button, create a new `Source` instance as the binding source instead of using the used instance, which can help you refresh the data source.

Comment: Ah yes, that works. Although unfortunately I don't think creating new instances will work in my actual project since I still need to use the original. For context, the buttons are actually tabs in a TabView. "Source" refers to an entire page in a TabViewItem. Source contains information about a canvas, where the Items collection contain info about layers that make up a canvas bitmap drawn on the page. The TreeView switches to display the data from the page (Source) in the active tab.

Comment: I see, maybe you can do this: a `Tab` corresponds to a `Frame`, and the `Frame` navigates to the specified page. With (Page) `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;` in your page constructor method, you don't have to refresh the entire page's data, it will keep the state when you left.

Comment: I gave it a go with navigation and NavigationCacheMode Enabled/Required but the initial problem starts happening again once it's enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this issue was shipped with Microsoft.UI.Xaml v2.4.0. See this [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/pull/2058) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reply.

We researched your problem, this problem has been fixed in the new [Microsoft.UI.Xaml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml/2.2.190917002) (`WinUI` 2.x). You can check this [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/pull/1387).

`WinUI` is a new generation of Microsoft's open source UI tool framework. Thanks to community support, it can be updated faster. We recommend that you use the `TreeView` control provided by it to complete your UI layout.

Best regards.

Comment: I gave it a go in the latest prerelease but sadly I'm still getting the same issue as before? I took a look at the related test page and tried to use the ExtendedObservableCollection with ReplaceAll() as it does, but like before, populating the collection that ItemSource is set to, with the items from a collection that the TreeView had displayed previously (i.e. in the event the user decides to return to the data set they were looking at before) all child nodes are then missing in the TreeView - root nodes are fine.

Comment: Hi, I tested your code using `ObservableCollection`, but did not reproduce your problem, can you provide an implementation of `ExtendedObservableCollection`?

Comment: Updated my post to include `ExtendedObservableCollection` and a Gif showing exactly what I'm seeing. (Using muxc version 2.3.191127001-prerelease)

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced your problem, you can consider submitting a new issue in [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues), and report your problem to the development team of WinUI.